How to indent longtblr
I'm trying to indent the longtblr, but it seems that \noindent has no effect on longtblr. How can I make it work?
Thanks a lot!
Here is what I've tried:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\parindent}{36pt}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}


\begin{document}

This line is indented.

\noindent This line is NOT indented. The following table is indented

\begin{longtblr}{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec={|X[1,l,t]|X[2,l,t]|}
    }
    \hline
    item 1 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
    item 2 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\noindent This line is NOT indented. The following table is NOT indented

\noindent\begin{longtblr}{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec={|X[1,l,t]|X[2,l,t]|}
    }
    \hline
    item 1 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
    item 2 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



welcome! you've specified it should be \linewidth, so if you indent it, it will exceed the width of the text block. do you actually want a narrower table?

I'm also guessing longtblr follows longtable and centres by default.

You could do \begin{longtblr}[r]{ width=\linewidth-\parindent, ... 

It seems that there is no option to add some horizontal spacing before a longtblr environment. One could probbaly ask the package author to add this.

It seems that there is no easy way to add horizontal spacing before a longtblr environment.
Also, I am not 100% sure that I understand your aim, but I take it that you want the table to be as wide as the text body. So, what you could do is setting the halign of the whole table to r (right-aligned) (by using \begin{longtblr}[r]) and set the width to \linewidth-\parindent. The result will be the same as if the table was indented.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\parindent}{36pt}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}

\begin{document}

This line is indented.

\noindent This line is NOT indented. The following table is indented

\begin{longtblr}[r]{
        width=\linewidth-\parindent,
        colspec={|X[1,l,t]|X[2,l,t]|}
    }
    \hline
    item 1 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
    item 2 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\noindent This line is NOT indented. The following table is NOT indented

\begin{longtblr}{
        width={\linewidth},
        colspec={|X[1,l,t]|X[2,l,t]|}
    }
    \hline
    item 1 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
    item 2 & specification 1, specification 2, ...\\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


If you want the indent on both sides, keep the table centered and set the width to \linewidth-2\parindent.

It is not a nice solution though =(

Thank you, but how do you apply change to halign?

@Rekkhan I just added [r] after \begin{longtblr}. This is an outer specification where the key can be omitted.

many thanks, I marked your solution as the answer.
